# Do I Need to Migrate to Link my Database to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working on a project that I inherited, and I want to add a table to my database that is very similar to one that already exists. Basically, we have a table to log users for our website, and I want to create a second table to specifically log users that our site fails to do a task for.

Since I didn't write the site myself, and am pretty new to both SQL and Django, I'm a little paranoid about running a migration (we have a lot of really sensitive data that I'm paranoid about wiping).

Instead of having a django migration create the table itself, can I create the second table in MySQL, and the corresponding model in Django, and then have this model "recognize" the SQL table? without explicitly using a migration?

Comment: If you have a lot of sensitive data you're paranoid about wiping the first thing you should be doing is immediately creating a backup and working on a development environment instead of a production database. I don't care if you're using Django, Rails, .NET, or whatever. If you can't completely and utterly destroy something you're coding against the problem isn't the lack of knowledge about a specific technology, the problem is you haven't set yourself up with a proper development environment.

Comment: You're right, and I'm trying to get a dev server set up. I work at a small political organization that's not exactly enterprise grade.

Comment: For what it's worth this is coming from a guy who has to independently manage large projects without a team behind him ( well team members who do any coding anyhow)

I actually think this is *more* important the smaller the team because the larger your responsibilities are the more likely you are to accidentally do something stupid.

If you explain to your boss/client "I can work with what's there fast and take a huge risk that I destroy everything there, or I can work a little slower and set up a risk free environment" they'll usually make the decision to set up the dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER: Yes.

MEDIUM ANSWER: Yes.  But you will have to figure out how Django would have created the table, and do it by hand.  That's not terribly hard.

Django may also spit out some warnings on startup about migrations being needed...but those are warnings, and if the app works, then you're OK.

LONG ANSWER:  Yes.  But for the sake of your sanity and sleep quality, get a completely separate development environment and test your backups.  (But you knew that already.)

Comment: So, if I make a copy of the original table in MySQL, and create a corresponding copy of the original model, should it work?